# Invalid Use of Default Parameter Error While Performing an Insert

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, adodb, vba

I get an error thrown when I try to execute my command to insert a new row into my database. I believe the error is being thrown by Null values. Although I cannot be sure about that.

Here is my code:

```
Sub AddRows()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String  

Dim comm As ADODB.Command
Set comm = New ADODB.Command
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim getType As MultipleValues
Dim nullCheck As String

SQLStr = "Insert Into [Steve_Dev_Matrix] Values("
For i = 1 To 121
    'Get type
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "?,"
    Set param = New ADODB.Parameter
    param.Name = "Param" & i
    Set param = comm.CreateParameter("param" & i, CLng(CellType(i, Cells(2, i).Value).CellType), adParamInput, CellType(i, Cells(2, i).Value).CellNum)
    param.Attributes = adParamNullable
    'Debug.Print (param.Type)
    comm.Parameters.Append param
Next i
SQLStr = Left(SQLStr, Len(SQLStr) - 1) & ");"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.CommandTimeout = 0
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

comm.ActiveConnection = Cn
comm.CommandText = SQLStr
comm.CommandType = adCmdText


Dim test As String
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'For x = 2 To lastrow
    For i = 1 To 121
        Debug.Print (comm.Parameters.Item("Param" & i).Type)
        comm.Parameters.Item("Param" & i).Value = Cells(2, i).Value
    Next
    comm.Execute

 '            Tidy up
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also here is an example of the CellType method:

```
Private Function CellType(Num, Rng) As MultipleValues
Application.Volatile
Select Case True
    Case Num = 1
        CellType.CellType = adInteger
    Case Num = 2
        CellType.CellType = adInteger
    Case Num = 3
        CellType.CellType = adVarWChar
        CellType.CellNum = 255
    Case Num = 4
        CellType.CellType = adCurrency
    Case Num = 5
        CellType.CellType = adVarWChar
        CellType.CellNum = 255
```

The error says: Invalid use of default parameter

Comment: Why not convert this into a stored procedure and then add your parameters to the procedure call. Building up a query like this just screams debugging nightmare to me.

Comment: I've never used a stored procedure. I guess I will have to do some research on it. Thanks

Comment: @SeanLange I did as you said and converted it to a stored procedure! Thanks for the help. The program runs perfectly now!

Comment: Cool. As you get more comfortable with stored procedures you will find they are way better than ad hoc sql. If you need to change the query you don't have to redeploy the entire application, simply change the procedure. It is a great first step in creating separate layers in your application.